# PHP Error. Unparenthesized a b c d e is deprecated. use either (a b c) d e or a b (c d e)

Tags: php

I am using PHP 7.4 on my site [www.miroliva.com](http://www.miroliva.com) and the error has arisen in this line

```
<header id="header" class="<?php echo esc_attr( ( is_front_page() ) ? 'intro-image': 'intro-blog' ); ?> <?php echo esc_attr( $parallax_class ); ?> <?php echo esc_attr( $menu_style ); ?>" style="background-image: url(' <?php echo esc_url( ( is_front_page() ) ? $intro_image : ( ! get_header_image() ) ? $intro_image : get_header_image() ); ?>');">
```

I don't know how I can solve it

any opinion???

thank you very much!!

Comment: Can we get the *exact* error message please…?

Comment: `esc_url( ( is_front_page() ) ? $intro_image : ( ! get_header_image() ) ? $intro_image : get_header_image() )` -- your parentheses are wrong, double-check them.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this messy spaghetti of ternary code, keep your code clean and separate logic from output. It is way more readable and you can trace errors much faster. Plus you then will see you execute `get_header_image()` twice for 1 result:

```
... :(!get_header_image()) ? //<< once
    $intro_image : 
    get_header_image()       //<< twice
    );
```

So, do something like this

```
//LOGIC
<?php 
$class=[];
    $class[] = esc_attr( (is_front_page()) ? 'intro-image' : 'intro-blog' );
    $class[] = esc_attr( $parallax_class );
    $class[] = esc_attr( $menu_style );
$class = implode(' ',$class);

if( is_front_page() ){
    $url = esc_url( $intro_image );
    }
else{ 
    $header_image = get_header_image();
    if( !$header_image ){
        $url = esc_url( $intro_image );
        }
    else{
        $url = esc_url( $header_image );
        }
    }
?>

//OUTPUT
<header 
    id="header" 
    class="<?php echo $class;?>" 
    style="background-image: url('<?php echo $url;?>');"
    >
```

The error you get is in this part:

```
( is_front_page() ) 
    ?   $intro_image 
                    ( << add extra parenthese 
    :   ( ! get_header_image() )   
        ?   $intro_image 
        :   get_header_image() 
                    ) << add extra parenthese
```

Comment: thank you very much!!!

the code was the one for the theme I was using, I hadn't touched it, apart from the fact that my knowledge is not very "advanced"

It works as a thousand wonders

Comment: No problem. Just keep your code as structured as possible, it will work wonders with tracing errors. Plus, in a few months time you still can see in a glance what you have done, instead of trying to unravel the spaghetti first.

Answer (score 2):

If you look carefully on the exact error message it will [give you all what you need](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.deprecated.php):

```
Unparenthesized a ? b : c ? d : e is deprecated. Use either (a ? b : c) ? d : e or a ? b : (c ? d : e)
```

When you're using [Ternary Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (i.e. `a ? b : c`) and stack them together (`a ? b : c ? d : e`, the behavior of PHP is different from other languages.

In php it will be considered as `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` while in many other languages it will be `a ? b : (c ? b : e)`.

This is a source of common mistakes. To avoid that mistakes, PHP just made those chain of ternary operators deprecated without parentheses.

To solve the issue just add the parentheses where you need them.

```
<header id="header" class="<?php 
   echo esc_attr(
       ( is_front_page() ) ? 'intro-image': 'intro-blog' ); 
   ?> <?php 
     echo esc_attr( $parallax_class ); 
   ?> <?php 
     echo esc_attr( $menu_style ); 
   ?>" style="background-image: url(' <?php
     echo esc_url( 
        ( is_front_page() ) ? $intro_image : (( // add parenthesis here 
 ! get_header_image() ) ? $intro_image : get_header_image() ) // and another here
      ); 
    ?>');">
```

And I beg you: format your code, don't put it all in a single line